# Meaning of percent change chart of google analytic

Tags: google-analytics

I'm a newbie user of google analytic.

And I realize that I don't understand one chart in home section of google analytic.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't understand about the dot line. What does it try to express/explain? It doesn't like to express percentage change.

Please let me know more if you know.

Thank in advance,

Jame

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh. so please tell me how to move it to webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: you cant you will have to recreate it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dotted line shows you the same metric for the preceding same-length period - i.e the 28 days before the time range you're looking at.